# API working when using curl but returns 400 error when using requests.post

Tags: curl, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use an API via Docker to predict captions for an image with the [MAX-Image-Caption-Generator-Model](https://github.com/IBM/MAX-Image-Caption-Generator). When using the curl command

```
curl -F "image=@example.jpg" -X POST http://localhost:8090/model/predict
```

it works perfectly, but when I tried doing the same from a python script using the requests module, I got a 400 error with the text

> {"errors": {"image": "An image file Missing required parameter in an uploaded file"}, "message": "Input payload validation failed"}

Here is my code:

```
import requests

data = open('example.jpg', 'rb')
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8090/model/predict', data=data)

print(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text)
```

I also tried

```
import requests

files = {
    'image': open('example.jpg', 'rb')
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8090/model/predict', files=files)

print(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text)
```

but got the error

> Invalid file type/extension. Please provide an image in JPEG or PNG format.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your file_to_upload variable should probably be:

```
file_to_upload = [
    ('image': ('example.jpg', open('example.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'))
]
```

it should be a list of tuples,  for each tuple the first item is the form field name and the second item is a tuple with the name, content and content type of the file.  in your case its only the one file.

this is based on the information found here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files